# Why does my CPU frequency never get a Turboboost?

Tags: linux, hardware, intel, cpu-frequency

So it's an oldish machine Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz but it's supposed to go up to 2.8GHz

If I 'watch' this, it never really changes much from 798MHz:

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "^[c]pu MHz"
cpu MHz     : 798.204
cpu MHz     : 798.254
cpu MHz     : 798.213
cpu MHz     : 798.210
cpu MHz     : 798.213
cpu MHz     : 798.225
cpu MHz     : 798.265
cpu MHz     : 798.356
```

... even if I put a single threaded load on:

```
$ echo "scale=10000; 4*a(1)" | bc -l
```

i7z shows this:

```
Cpu speed from cpuinfo 1995.00Mhz
cpuinfo might be wrong if cpufreq is enabled. To guess correctly try estimating via tsc
Linux's inbuilt cpu_khz code emulated now
True Frequency (without accounting Turbo) 1995 MHz
  CPU Multiplier 20x || Bus clock frequency (BCLK) 99.75 MHz

Socket [0] - [physical cores=4, logical cores=8, max online cores ever=4]
  TURBO ENABLED on 4 Cores, Hyper Threading ON
  Max Frequency without considering Turbo 2094.75 MHz (99.75 x [21])
  Max TURBO Multiplier (if Enabled) with 1/2/3/4 Cores is  29x/28x/26x/26x
  Real Current Frequency 798.34 MHz [99.75 x 8.00] (Max of below)
        Core [core-id]  :Actual Freq (Mult.)      C0%   Halt(C1)%  C3 %   C6 %  Temp      VCore
        Core 1 [0]:   798.34 (8.00x)        8.94    95.4       1       0    58  0.7455
        Core 2 [2]:   797.79 (8.00x)        9.02    95.3    1.05       0    55  0.7455
        Core 3 [4]:   797.97 (8.00x)        13.4    93.6 1  1.49       0    54  0.7505
        Core 4 [6]:   797.96 (8.00x)        10.2    94.9       1       0    53  0.7505
```

... is it maybe dying?

Comment: That looks like a laptop CPU. Is it running on battery power? Try plugging in a power adapter and see if you get different results then. The reason might be aggressive power management restricting the CPU to ~800 MHz clock frequency when running on battery.

Comment: Yes - a laptop, sorry I should have mentioned that. The battery is stuffed (replacement ordered) and I can only run on mains.

Comment: Huh? I never closed this one off. Sorry for that. The solution was a stuffed external power  supply which wasn't charging properly. The laptop could never get enough power to ramp up the CPU's. A new charger brought the machine back to its senses!